# Change from Windows Forms to WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013

I already made an application that is using Windows Forms, but I knew that Windows Forms setup was no longer available in Visual Studio 2013, that is made me to install both of Visual  Studio 2010 and Visual Studio 2013. When I want to make some changes in my application and re-build the setup, I have to run Visual Studio 2010 rather than Visual Studio 2013. The reason because I am using Visual Studio 2013, because I like this version and I am using Visual Studio 2010 just because for when I want to make some changes in my application.

I knew about WPF Applications when I finished made my application. And I am considering to uninstall Visual Studio 2010 and work with Visual Studio 2013. Do I have to re-write everything on my application's code to WPF? Because from what I heard, some functions in WPF are not the same in Windows Forms. And let's say that I successfully change my application from Windows Forms to WPF, what setup is provided with WPF ? So the other users could use my application on their computer?

Answer (score 3):

> i knew that Windows Forms setup has no longer available in Visual Studio 2013

Windows Forms is still available as a technology in Visual Studio 2013. If you are referring to the setup project type for creating an installer switching to WPF will not make it available for you.

So you can switch to Visual Studio 2013 and continue using Windows Forms but you will have to find another way to create an installer (and switching to WPF will **not** fix that problem).

In my opinion the [ViX Toolset](http://wixtoolset.org/) is very good for creating an installer. However, it is not "drag and drop" as the old Visual Studio Setup project type is.

Answer (score 0):

@Kaoru You have to make some changes, Because some of functions in WPF and Win Forms are different.You don't need to change the Application Logic. But you have to change some modifications in UI and also code.

I heard a tool something called [WF2WPF](http://wf2wpf.codeplex.com/) But I never used it and not found yet it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are missing installer projects in VS 2013, then you may want to try [Visual Studio Installer Projects Extension](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2014/04/17/visual-studio-installer-projects-extension.aspx).

> This preview release provides support for Visual Studio Installer projects in Visual Studio 2013. You can download the extension from the Visual Studio Gallery.